# sb admin 2 bootstrap login image stuck

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I have been trying for the past two hours to change the image on the login page from a dog to something else, checked all the files, both css and scss and changed the link everywhere, but still see this dog! I even tried deleting the code parts but still dog remained on its place, and no cache cleaning on browser helped either. Any ideas what could it be and what should i do?

Comment: You need to include some code so we can see what you are trying to change.

Comment: Does the dog appear in Chrome Incognito mode as well?

Comment: wow, no, it doesnt! Why does it affect?

Comment: It will be a local or server-level Cache. Make sure you are doing a hard refresh on your browser when you want to see changes you have made in code or CSS i.e, Ctrl + Shift + R

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is caused by a local or server-level cache. Always ensure you are performing a hard-refresh on your browser when you want to see changes you have made to your code. This is especially true when editing CSS files.

To perform a hard refresh just use **Ctrl + Shift + R**